# SQL Select post that has been replied to last (in same table)

Tags: sql

I have a weirdly set up imageboard thingy. Simplified, the table looks like this:

```
+----------------------------+
| id | replyto | text        |
+----------------------------+
| 1  |         | new thread  |
| 2  |   1     | I'm a reply |
+----------------------------+
```

Now what I want to to do, is to get the thread that was last replied to, and it's contents (in this case "text". If you've visited an imageboard you surely know what I'm talking about.

Comment: "If you've visited an imageboard you surely know what I'm talking about".  If you care about the problem, you can surely take the time to explain what you are really looking for.

Comment: More importantly - if you can't be bothered to give a full question you'll probably understand why no one will bothered to reply. Please review this and edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I know you say that you've 'simplified' the table by providing only those 3 columns but your problem is impossible to solve using only those 3 columns. There must be a date or timestamp field indicating when the post was made. Can you provide all of the columns on the table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did explain what I wanted properly.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Yes I did not realise that the timestamp would be relevat, thought we could do the same with the ID

Comment: @impedans probably could if it's an auto_increment field, in my answer below you can replace each instance of "post_time" with id and compare

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Thanks:) Yes it is auto_incremented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.*
  from your_table t
  join (select max(id) as last_id
          from your_table
         where replyto is not null) v
    on t.id = v.last_id
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/950a1/1/0

Comment: What does "select t.*" mean?

Comment: select * from the table aliased as t